# Two way data binding nativescript from class

Tags: angular, nativescript, typescript2.0, angular2-nativescript

How to achieve TWO Way binding in Nativescript ?

Below is what i have tried . The variable CompModel contains a value  "FA I Test".

I want to be able to bind data both ways that is what is set at the class level FA I Test" and then whatever value the user changes in textbox on click of the button the value to be displayed .

> ```
>     import { Component } from "@angular/core";
> import { DependencyObservable } from "ui/core/dependency-observable";
> import { Observable } from "data/observable";
>
>
> @Component({
>   selector: "my-app",
>   template: `
>     <ActionBar title="My App 2"></ActionBar>
>     <!-- Your UI components go here -->
>     <StackLayout>
>     <TextView [(ngModel)]='CompModel.Name'></TextView>
>     <Button text="Click" (tap)="Clicked()"></Button>
>     </StackLayout>
>   `
> })
> export class AppComponent {
>   // Your TypeScript logic goes here
>   public CompModel: Plain;
>
>   constructor(){
>     this.CompModel = new Plain();
>     this.CompModel.Name= "FA I TEST";
>   }
>   Clicked(obj){
>     alert(this.CompModel.Name);
>   }
> }
>
> export class Plain {
>   public Name : String;
>   constructor(){
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have registered the `NativeScriptFormsModule`:

```
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms"

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule // <-- this will enable 2-way binding
    ],
    ...
})
```